# What's the difference in meaning between "grandiose" and "elaborate"?

Tags: meaning

What's the difference in meaning between adjectives:
"grandiose" and 
"elaborate" ?

Comment: "*impressive or magnificent in appearance or style*" versus "*involving many carefully arranged parts or details*." This appears to be a general-reference question. Do you have a specific point of confusion about the definitions?

Comment: In principle, something that's *grandiose* could be extremely *simple* (but, say, extremely ***large***), so it might not be at all "elaborate".

Comment: Something that is *grandiose* is something large, elegant, and/or extravagant that is intended to impress the viewer.  Something that is *elaborate* is inherently complex; while the impact of seeing the complexity may be to impress the viewer, the intent is to perform a complex function.  More simply, grandiose is "form over function" while elaborate is "function over form".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Elaborate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/elaborate):

> The adjective elaborate is used to describe when something is planned with a lot of attention to detail or when something is intricate or detailed itself. 
>   [image]

vs

[Grandiose](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/grandiose):

> The adjective grandiose is used to describe unnecessary largeness or grandeur; and it's that excessiveness that pushes something grand (large, with an air of distinction) into grandiose (large, but trying too hard) territory.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

So, as hinted at already, "grandiose" is inherently derogatory and pejorative (negative.)  You are wise to ponder the connotation as well as the explicit definition. It's never nice to call someone, or their efforts, grandiose— it is insulting.  To compliment them, say "how magnificent" (of efforts or results) or "how magnanimous" (of a person). A magnanimous person is doing grand things out of a kind heart, with generosity; whereas a grandiose person is acting out of egotism and a desire for self-promotion.

You would enjoy a thesaurus; for almost every adjective it seems there is always a near-synonym with a more negative or more positive connotation. consider, for example, this incomplete continuum of terms that describe "confidently doing or advocating one thing that you think is right (despite what others might think)". Every one of them has a different connotation.
- courageous
- brave
- bold
- trailblazing
- passionate
- visionary
- go-getter
- outlier
- self-assured
- steadfast
- assertive
- direct
- single-minded
- persistent
- determined
- crusading
- eccentric
- dogged
- zealous
- marches to a different drummer
- devil-may-care
- unstoppable
- driven
- insistent
- aggressive
- strong-willed
- pushy
- intransigent
- steamroller
- one-track mind
- bossy
- overbearing
- bulldozer
- fanatic
- kooky
- belligerent
- obsessed
- reckless
- monomaniacal